# How will a conductor charged with a single electron, redistribute the charge to the surface?

Tags: electrostatics

I know how there can be no 'free' charges inside of a conductor as these free charges will be moved to the surface of the conductor. If the charge is due to free electrons then these electrons redistribute themselves onto the surface. The reason for this is given as: the free electrons repel each other and so move to the boundary where they feel the least repulsive force. But what if there is just a single free 'extra' electron inside the conductor? Why would this charge move to the surface as there are no other free electrons to repel this electron?

Answer (score 1):

You mean [this](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/gausur.html)  conductor at  equilibrium argument:

1. The net electric charge of a conductor resides entirely on its surface. (The mutual repulsion of like charges from Coulomb's Law demands that the charges be as far apart as possible, hence on the surface of the conductor.)

Note that the concept is completely classical, *charges*, not *electrons*.

Electrons are quantum mechanical entities and if one wants to talk about them one needs quantum mechanical models, as the band theory of solids.

[image: bands]

In a neutral conductor there still are "free electrons" in the conduction band, the ones that build up the current if a voltage difference is imposed. They are bound to the whole metal lattice and not to individual atoms.

A single electron introduced on the surface will stay on the surface as all the available energy levels are filled in a neutral conductor. I do not see how a single electron could be introduced in a conductor other than through a surface.

I found [this link](https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft/six.pdf) that derives Gauss' law from quantum electrodynamics, so the whole is consistent,

Comment: Thank you. I am coming from a background in fluid/CFD, thermal engineering. Since the charge is a conserved quantity I am explaining it to myself by making an analogy b/w charge redistribution for electrostatic equilibrium with thermal equilibrium(continuum view of charge). Any 'extra' electron placed at the center of a conductor would affect the charges all around it, so as to slightly move them in such a way that the combined effect on the initial 'extra' charge is neutralized. The charge is redistributed all around the boundary whose are integral should be the initial charge?

Comment: This would be same as how temperature/energy is throughout a conductor from a hot spot.

Comment: @GRANZER temperature is not a good model for quantum mechanical states, and a single electorn needs a quantum mechanical model.

Comment: No, I wish to understand electrostatics/dynamics from the classical perspective before going for a quantum mechanics! But I see your point about the problem of asking about a 'single electron'! Can you please answer one additional question? If a 'charge' is placed at a point on the boundary of the insulator why doesn't it redistribute due to polarisation? It says so in the second paragraph of [this](https://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/estatics/Lesson-1/Conductors-and-Insulators). I can understand why 'electrons' won't move from a point in conductor but shouldn't charge redistribute?

Comment: @GRANZER an insulator by classical definition does not allow movement of charges  this first sentence, https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insulator_(electricity) . Unfortunately  the microsopic view of current being flow of electrons, a smiclassical picture, confuses the issue. (because the electons forming the current is easily understood) http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/miccur.html . The mobility of charge on an insulator is prohibited because current cannot form.

Answer (score 1):

A conductor with a single free electron is a rather exotic concept. Without that one electron it must be an insulator. So consider an insulator with an electron trap at the surface whete your extra electron resides. In this case you know where the extra electron is but the charge is still spread out due to polarisation. If that single electron is free to move you will also not know where it is due quantum mechanics.

Comment: Why will it be an insulator without that extra electron?. Let you consider the conductor is made up of 10 protons and 10 electrons. The electrons are free to move about and the net charge of the conductor is still zero. If we add an additional electron, so the total electrons are 11 then the conductor is called charged ryt?

Comment: The part where you talk about the redistribution of charge in an insulator is confusing for me. According to $\[https://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/estatics/Lesson-1/Conductors-and-Insulators ]$ the charge cannot get redistributed in an insulator (Written in second paragraph "In contrast to conductors, insulators are materials that impede the free flow of electrons from atom to atom and molecule to molecule. If charge is transferred to an insulator at a given location, the excess charge will remain at the initial location of charging...")

Comment: I get it now what you meant by it would be an insulator!! You are saying all other electrons will not be free as inbound to the nucleus!  When I said free-electron I mean 'extra' electron!

Comment: In an insulator there is polarisation, which effectively spreads out charge

Comment: Thank you! So if we transfer a charge 'Q' to a point 'P' on a spherical insulator, the charge 'Q' acts as a source of a non-uniform electric field. The insulator material close to this point gets polarised. This means there are (bound) charges and non-zero electric fields up to a certain depth inside the insulator. Can we say that the charge 'Q' at the initial point is reduced by a little bit and redistributed to the inner depth of the insulator?

Comment: Yes the charge Q is screened and the insulator is polarized. So-called bound charge appears where the divergency of the polarization density is non-zero.